# django 'urlize' strings form text just like twitter

Tags: django, url, text, string, parsing

heyy there

i want to parse a text,let's name it 'post', and 'urlize' some strings if they contain a particular character, in a particular position.

my 'pseudocode' trial would look like that:

```
 def urlize(post)
      for string in post
      if string icontains ('#')
      url=(r'^searchn/$',
                    searchn,
                    name='news_searchn'),
     then apply url to the string
     return urlize(post)
```

i want the function to return to me the post with the urlized strings, where necessary (just like twitter does).

i don't understand: how can i parse a text, and search for certain strings?
is there ok to make a function especially for 'urlizing' some strings? The function should return the entire post, no matter if it has such kind of strings.
is there another way Django offers?
Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of an input (with a #) and output (with a link) strings?

Comment: Dana, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? It seems like you are looking to implement a custom behavior (not the classic urlize), so a custom template tag is naturally the way to go.

Comment: my intention is to build a mini blog that works just like twitter.
When someone posts a text containing a word with the format: #something, the #something should be a link that goes to all the posts of all the users containing that word #something.

How can i parse the text looking for the #-word?

Comment: I edited my answer with how to find the #words.

Comment: wow,so cool! thank you! 

i have to study a bit about regex stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I guess you mostly need this function in templates (you want to present the post "urlized").

There's the built-in [template tag urlize](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize), which is used like

```
{{ value|urlize }}
```

which takes a string value and returns it with links.

If you want to customize the logic, you can [create your own template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

**EDIT:**
To find the # words you can use a simple regex search:

```
import re
a = "hello #world. foo #bar! #foo_bar"
re.findall("#(\w+)",a)

>> ['world', 'bar', 'foo_bar']
```